# Ajax request in rails 3.2 hitting controller twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, erb

I have an ajax call for my signup, but this ends up hitting the controller twice. I tested this using the debugger, so I am sure it hits it twice. Why does it do this?

Code for the controller is this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in(@user)
  end
end
```

This goes to create.js.erb, which is this.

```
<% if current_user %>
  $('.sign-up').remove();
  $('.sign-in').remove();
  $('div.top a.disabled').remove();
  $('div.top').append('<a class="bookmarklet" href="javascript:<%= bookmarklet_caller_js %>">DRAG ME</a>');
  $('nav').append('<%= j render "layouts/signed_in" %>');
  $('nav').find('div.alert').remove();
  $('nav').prepend('<div class="alert">Successfully signed up');
<% else %>
  $('nav').prepend('<div class="alert">Error in signing up');
<% end %>
```

The call works as intended. But on user signup success it runs the loop twice, hence it signs the user up but the error message is overwritten by the failure one.

Any idea why this would happen?

My public assets folder.

```
Shivams-MacBook-Pro:Resource_It shivamd$ cd public/assets/
application-6bff97b14b282b79979adb4ef1e76e97.css  
application-  f41a09e268b5715d39683efc0ea7d95f.css.gz 
jquery.min-6c267bfd2b3f36e6edccb2e584934c1c.map
application-6bff97b14b282b79979adb4ef1e76e97.css.gz 
application.css                           
jquery.min.map
application-8dd88800030e4c48315ff31ade093d00.css     
application.css.gz                        
manifest.yml
application-8dd88800030e4c48315ff31ade093d00.css.gz  
application.js                                       
rails-a3386665c05a2d82f711a4aaa72d247c.png
application-dc9a8b23a4c79a4934d3d64cf1146042.js      
application.js.gz                                    
rails.png
application-dc9a8b23a4c79a4934d3d64cf1146042.js.gz   
grey-pattern-f166bfdb393cc4dd8c23d00665ba7da9.png    
application-f41a09e268b5715d39683efc0ea7d95f.css     
grey-pattern.png
```

And my ajax call is being done with remote true

Comment: check if you are loading jquery.js twice, it also cause the problem

Comment: Do you use `remote: true` on the form, or a custom ajax request in javascript? If you use javascript, then please submit the relevant js code.

Comment: As @Salil suggests, this has also happened to me. In my case it was because of a precompiled copy of the jquery asset being included along with the copy in the assets folder.

Comment: How do I check that? When I inspect my head it's only there once. I have included my public/assets folder. How do I prevent this from happening if it is @Salil

Comment: Yes my ajax call is being done with remote true